# Using DateTime in MariaDB 10.3.9 system versioned tables works for rowStart but not rowEnd

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm testing out system versioned tables in MariaDB 10.3.9 - but I'd like to version past `2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999` because I'm assuming I'll still be around in 19 years. To that end I'm using `DATETIME(6)` instead of `TIMESTAMP(6)`. This does not work. The `AS ROW END` generation comes out as `0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000`.

As a result, I cannot select or alter the current state of the table. Is this a bug or am I missing some configuration option, implementation detail that makes `DATETIME` unfeasible?

Here's the printout from a test session:

```
MariaDB [tests]> CREATE TABLE dateTimeTest
    -> (
    ->   dtt_id       INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   dtt_value    VARCHAR(6)   NOT NULL,
    ->   dtt_rowStart DATETIME(6)           GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START,
    ->   dtt_rowEnd   DATETIME(6)           GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END,
    ->   PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME(dtt_rowStart, dtt_rowEnd),
    ->   --
    ->   PRIMARY KEY DTT_pk(dtt_id)
    -> ) WITH SYSTEM VERSIONING;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.057 sec)

MariaDB [tests]> INSERT INTO dateTimeTest (dtt_value)
    -> VALUES ('valueA'),
    ->        ('valueB');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.009 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [tests]> SELECT *
    -> FROM dateTimeTest;
Empty set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [tests]> SELECT * FROM dateTimeTest FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL;
+--------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| dtt_id | dtt_value | dtt_rowStart               | dtt_rowEnd                 |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|      1 | valueA    | 2018-10-04 20:49:50.763456 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000 |
|      2 | valueB    | 2018-10-04 20:49:50.763456 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000 |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [tests]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be around, but it won't be.  Walk with me through a thought exercise...

19 years ago, MySQL was in version 3.xx running MyISAM only.  And Windows was running a version that will not run today unless you saved that old hardware.  And it had much less than 1GB of RAM and the backups were probably on floppies.  (Remember floppies?)  And the display device was a CRT connected with a VGA cable.  (When did you last see a CRT?)

Would you trust anything that old?  Could you even get it to run?

How can you keep alive something for 19 years?  You *must* upgrade *everything* every 5 years -- hardware, input device, output devices, memory, storage, OS, MySQL, etc, etc.

Shift forward 19 years.

I claim you will need to do 4 major upgrades between now and 2038.  Dealing with the Y-2038 problem will be just one minor thing to deal with.

If you do need to peek ahead, you can at least use `DATE` until the Y10K problem arises.  That will be long after we are dead.

Comment: While I agree that we should be updating software regularly, I'm assuming we both know that that doesn't always happen. I've dealt with legacy systems, and at least one of them is still running a dBase version from the early 90s. The last 'upgrade' to that mission critical system was to virtualize it.

This leads me to be concerned about this sort of thing. 

I don't see a good reason as to why the devs of MariaDB would consciously choose TIMESTAMP over DATETIME as a method of storing archival information. If anything, that's what I want to know - the Datatype is there, why not use it?

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` is stored as UTC; `DATETIME` is local time.  With local time, and with DST, time can seem to jump backward -- this would not be good for a system that needs ordering.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. The documentation doesn't exactly make that difference clear. I never had to really deal with it since I'd always run servers in UTC anyways. It makes dealing with client timezones a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some discussion about `DATETIME` and system-versioning tables. In short, it's disallowed intentionally and someday there will be a data type with a broader range. https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17448